# Not able to select the iframe in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have 3 iframes as below:

```
<iframe id="contentframe" name="content" src="images/loading.gif?RN=6.3_HF10" class="" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" onLoad="setTrailMargin();"></iframe>

<iframe id="linkTrailFrame" src='images/blank.gif?RN=6.3_HF10' name="linkTrailFrame" class="linkTrailFrame" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

<iframe id="ChildMenuIFrm" src='images/blank.gif?RN=6.3_HF10' name="ChildMenuIFrame" class="SubObjectNavCollpase" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 style="display::none"></iframe>
```

`driver.switchTo().frame("id");` is working for the second and third `iframe`, but not working for the first `iframe`.

Answer (score 3):

Are you switching to frames one by one? After every switch to one frame you have to come out to the main content before making a switch to the next frame

```
webdriver.switchto().Frame(<FirstFrame>);
webdriver.switchto().defaultcontent();
webdriver.switchto().Frame(<SecondFrame>);
```

you can learn more about Iframes here http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/handling-iframes-using-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: No I have to only go to in frame 1st. I have seen difference in iframe 1st is   = onLoad="setTrailMargin();....I have no idea about it how to handle